# IE8 и ниже. Не работает font-face

Tags: шрифты, html, css

Всем привет. Сконвертил шрифт с помощью font2web (хотя это не важно, вроде бы). Вот код font-face:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadProCond';
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/cond/MyriadPro-Cond.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/cond/MyriadPro-Cond.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/cond/MyriadPro-Cond.svg') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Везде все замечательно, а вот в IE8 и 7 не работает. Не могу понять почему.

Для навигации, например, пишу, как и надо:

```
#nav {
    font-family: 'MyriadProCond';
}
```

font Для body такой (там еще один шрифт подключается - regular):

```
body {
    font: 14px/20px 'MyriadPro', Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: @inferus-vv, извините, поспешил. Попробуйте [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), как известно с опыта, генерированые в нём шрифты идут под IE8

Comment: @crasher опять же проблема.. Даже две. Ну во первых MyriadPro он конвертировать не будет, так как это запрещено Adobe'ом. Ну а во вторых, когда я использовал это конвертер для других шрифтов, кириллицу он удалял, как бы я не крутил настройки.. Вот такие вот дела :)

Comment: @inferus-vv, плохо крутили настройки, на других шрифтах у меня получалось сохранять кириллицу. Unicode ranges: 410-451

Comment: Ок. Я попробую на каком нибудь шрифте. Но MyriadPro он не будет конвертировать из за лицензии (или как там)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что браузер IE до 8 версии включительно поддерживает только один формат шрифтов - EOT.
[Доказательство.](http://caniuse.com/fontface)
Переконвертируйте Ваш шрифт в этот формат и будем Вам счастье!

Comment: Так есть он. Вот с таким кодом пробую также. Не работает: http://jsfiddle.net/jCjNL/

Comment: Ну в Вашем примере синтаксис правильный, но как прикажите его проверить если стили не подключены?

Comment: В смысле? Все подключено. В других браузерах работает

Comment: url('../fonts/cond/MyriadPro-Cond.eot');
из примера. Я оговорился и имел ввиду, что не подключены сами шрифты в примере.

Answer (score 1):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadProCond';
    src: url('../fonts/cond/MyriadPro-Cond.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/cond/MyriadPro-Cond.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/cond/MyriadPro-Cond.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/cond/MyriadPro-Cond.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/cond/MyriadPro-Cond.svg#MyriadProCond') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Вы по ссылке автора ходили и код смотрели?

Comment: Ха, видимо, из одного источника взяли - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582401/css-font-face-not-working-in-ie8
Когда-то именно этот вариант мне помог, нашел в закладках, решил поделиться.